# How to check the index value from the list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, indexing

I need some help with my code. I want to check that if the value for `self.channels_index` is no greater or equal than `self.channel` so I can fetch the element from the list. If the value is greater than `self.channel` value then don't do anything.

When I try this:

```
self.channels_Index += 1

for index in enumerate(self.channel):
    if index > self.channels_Index:
       new_channel = self.channel[self.channels_Index]
```

I will get an error: IndexError: list index out of range.

The error are highlight on this line:

```
new_channel = self.channel[self.channels_Index]
```

There is no value after the last element from the list.

Here is the `self.channel` list:

```
 ['101 BBC One S East', '102 BBC Two', '103 ITV', '104 Channel 4', '105 Channel 5', '106 Sky One', '107 Sky Living', '108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK', '403 Sky Sports 3 UK', '404 Sky Sports 4 UK', '405 Sky Sports 5 UK', '406 Sky Sports News HQ', '407 Sky Sports F1', '408 Sky Sports 1 HD', '409 Sky Sports 2 HD', '410 Sky Sports 3 HD', '411 Sky Sports 4 HD', '412 Sky Sports 5 HD', '413 Eurosport 1 UK', '414 Eurosport 2 UK', '415 BT Sport 1', '416 BT Sport 2', '417 At the Races', '418 BT Sport ESPN', '419 MUTV', '420 Chelsea TV', '421 Eir Sport 1', '422 Eir Sport 2']
```

What I am expecting to achieve is I am using the `self.channels_index` to add the value and check with the `self.channel` value so I can fetch the element using the value until I can get the last element from the list which it is `422 Eir Sport 2`

Can you please show me an example how I can use `self.channels_index` to check with the `self.channel` value to see that if the value is equal or no greater than the last value so I can fetch the elements until I can get the last element from the list?

Comment: Try printing `index` - it's not what you think it is!

Comment: "What I am expecting to achieve is I am using the self.channels_index to add the value and check with the self.channel value so I can fetch the element using the value until I can get the last element from the list which it is 422 Eir Sport 2" - this is not clear!

Comment: what you dont get it?

Comment: I just wrote you exactly what I don't get... you're focusing on the *how* instead of the *what*. We shouldn't care about your implementation as much as we should understand *what* is it you're trying to achieve. You can start by: I have a list of values and I want to extract [...].

Comment: Oh right, well I have the list of values when I am using `self.channels_index` to add it up to each time and I want to extract the element from the list using with the values until when I can get the last element from the list. I hope it is clear?

Comment: "using self.channels_index to add it up to each time " - what does that mean? "I want to extract the element from the list using with the values" - which values ?

Comment: Oh come on. I dont need to say it all over again. READ THE CODE THAT i posted `self.channels += 1` that I add the value in each time and I want to get the value for the element from the list.

Comment: You are yelling at the guy that is trying to help you. Try to relax, take a deep breath and let me know if that's what you mean: "I want to slice the list starting at the index stored at `self.channels_index` until the end of the list" - is that what you mean ?

Comment: By the way, if you provided an example with (smaller) input and expected output - it would really help in understanding *what* is it you're trying to achieve...

Comment: what example you want to see?

Comment: I have been explained like 3 times and you never understand. Funny how people dont read my question carefully what I am trying to achieve. I am sure you know what I am trying to do as if I have the `self.channels_index` value as the `self.channel` has got 30 values so I want to fetch `102 BBC Two` from the list. There you go!

Comment: I am trying to create something like this `for index in range(len(self.channel)):
                 if not len(self.channels_Index) > index:
                     new_channel = self.channel[self.channels_Index]`

Comment: I give up... good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns a list of indexes and values. Observe:

```
>>> L = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey']
>>> list(enumerate(L))
[(0, 'hi'), (1, 'hello'), (2, 'hey')]
```

You'll need to modify your code to reflect this by having two variables in your for loop:

```
for index, val in enumerate(self.channel):
    if index > self.channels_Index:
       new_channel = val
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, but I want to fetch the element from the list using the value. Example: If I have the value `10`, I want to fetch `402 SKY Sports 2 UK` from the list. So if I have the value `30` then I want to fetch `422 Eir Sport 2`. If I have the value `31` or whatever it is which is greater than then I dont want to do anything. The code you post it will fetch the last element from the list which is wrong!

Comment: What I want to achieve is I want to fetch the elements from the list using the value like `'108 Sky Atlantic', '401 Sky Sports 1 UK', '402 SKY Sports 2 UK'` and so on until when I have the value 30 to get `422 Eir Sport 2`. I hope this is clear?